# removing a StorageMap from a pallet

Tags: frame, storagemap, storage-migration

I am looking to completely remove a `StorageMap` from the inclusion runtime module of the polkadot relay chain.
I am writing a migration for it and I'm wondering whether it's enough to call `clear` on the map: https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-sdk/master/frame_support/storage/types/struct.StorageMap.html#method.clear

Will `clear` delete all the stored data (including any metadata related to the map), or just the elements?

Looking at the implementation, it ends up calling `clear_prefix`, which should delete all info from the storage trie with the prefix, so I'm assuming this is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this will remove all the entries. The `StorageMap` itself doesn't has any metadata that is stored in the state. Before deleting the map, you should check the number of elements in it. Deleting millions of key/value pairs would take some time ;) In this case a multi-block migration would probably be better.